# Which other lands (besides Eretz Israel) have Kedushas Ha'aretz?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, chutz-laaretz, kedusha-holiness, chazal

I recently read this in a quasi-responsum online:

"Kilayim is specific to EY and areas that Hazal determined to have Q'dushas
Ha'aretz. Outside of this zone, Kilayim is not applicable."

(Source: http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol17/v17n020.shtml)

Does anyone know which places other than Israel the author was referring to when he mentioned "areas that Hazal determined to have Q'dushas Ha'aretz"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is probably referring to certain areas adjacent to Eretz Yisrael, and possibly to Suria (some part of modern day Syria) that share some of the "laws of the land", however they have a lesser level of *kedushah* and not all stringencies were applied to them. These are mentioned throughout the Mishna in Seder Zeraim.

Within Eretz Yisrael proper, there are also two areas - the land originally conquered by the Israelites after leaving Egypt, and a small area resanctified upon the return of the Jews from exile - see Mishna Shevi'is 6:1

Comment: Thanks afuna. So are the laws even stricter in those parts of E"Y?

Comment: @SAH When there is a difference in law, the E.Y. proper will always have the more stringent law. (Only the part conquered upon the return from exile had the *biblical* status of E.Y.